# Spring 3.2: Filtering Jackson JSON output based on Spring Security role

Tags: spring, spring-security, jackson

Is there any good way to filter JSON output based on Spring Security roles? I'm looking for something like @JsonIgnore, but for role, like @HasRole("ROLE_ADMIN"). How should I implement this?

Answer (score 20):

For those landing here from Google, here is a similar solution with Spring Boot 1.4.

Define interfaces for each of your roles, e.g.

```
public class View {
    public interface Anonymous {}

    public interface Guest extends Anonymous {}

    public interface Organizer extends Guest {}

    public interface BusinessAdmin extends Organizer {}

    public interface TechnicalAdmin extends BusinessAdmin {}
}
```

Declare `@JsonView` in your entities, e.g.

```
@Entity
public class SomeEntity {
    @JsonView(View.Anonymous.class)
    String anonymousField;

    @JsonView(View.BusinessAdmin.class)
    String adminField;
}
```

And define a `@ControllerAdvice` to pick up the right `JsonView` based on the roles:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class JsonViewConfiguration extends AbstractMappingJacksonResponseBodyAdvice {

    @Override
    public boolean supports(MethodParameter returnType, Class<? extends HttpMessageConverter<?>> converterType) {
        return super.supports(returnType, converterType);
    }

    @Override
    protected void beforeBodyWriteInternal(MappingJacksonValue bodyContainer, MediaType contentType,
                                           MethodParameter returnType, ServerHttpRequest request, ServerHttpResponse response) {

        Class<?> viewClass = View.Anonymous.class;

        if (SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getAuthorities() != null) {
            Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getAuthorities();

            if (authorities.stream().anyMatch(o -> o.getAuthority().equals(Role.GUEST.getValue()))) {
                viewClass = View.Guest.class;
            }
            if (authorities.stream().anyMatch(o -> o.getAuthority().equals(Role.ORGANIZER.getValue()))) {
                viewClass = View.Organizer.class;
            }
            if (authorities.stream().anyMatch(o -> o.getAuthority().equals(Role.BUSINESS_ADMIN.getValue()))) {
                viewClass = View.BusinessAdmin.class;
            }
            if (authorities.stream().anyMatch(o -> o.getAuthority().equals(Role.TECHNICAL_ADMIN.getValue()))) {
                viewClass = View.TechnicalAdmin.class;
            }
        }
        bodyContainer.setSerializationView(viewClass);
    }
}
```

Comment: Worked a treat for me, but note that you may also need to set the spring property `spring.jackson.mapper.default-view-inclusion=true` so you don't have to annotate every single property of your entities

Comment: This is an interesting approach. Please be aware though, that if you're working with Spring Data and define a projection, it will take preference over the view, possibly letting the user sideline the restrictions by passing a projection query parameter to the queries.

Comment: Is it possible to have a view which extends from multiple views? What should I do if I want to have a view which has the privilege of View1 and View2?

Answer (score 9):

## Update: The new Answer

you should consider using [rkonovalov/jfilter](https://github.com/rkonovalov/jfilter/). specially `@DynamicFilterComponent` helps a lot.
you can see a good guide in this [DZone](https://dzone.com/articles/spring-web-service-response-filtering) article.

`@DynamicFilterComponent` is explained [here](https://rkonovalov.github.io/projects/jfilter/1.0.8/examples/filter-dynamic/).

## The old answer

I've just implemented the requirement you've mentioned above. My system uses Restful `Jersey 1.17`, `Spring Security 3.0.7`, `Jackson 1.9.2`. But the solution has nothing to do with Jersey Restful API and you can use it on any other kind of Servlet implementations.

This is the entire 5 steps of my solution:

1. First you should create an Annotation class for your purpose, Like this:

   ### JsonSpringView.java

   ```
   import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
   import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;

   @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
   public @interface JsonSpringView {
       String springRoles();
   }
   ```
2. Then an Annotation Introspector, most of it's Methods should return `null`, Fill the Methods based on your need, for my requirments i had just used `isIgnorableField`. `Feature` is My Implementation For GrantedAuthority interface. Like this:

   ### JsonSpringViewAnnotationIntrospector.java

   ```
   @Component
   public class JsonSpringViewAnnotationIntrospector extends AnnotationIntrospector implements Versioned 
   {
       // SOME METHODS HERE
       @Override
       public boolean isIgnorableField(AnnotatedField)
       {
           if(annotatedField.hasAnnotation(JsonSpringView.class))
           {
               JsonSpringView jsv = annotatedField.getAnnotation(JsonSpringView.class);
               if(jsv.springRoles() != null)
               {
                   Object principal = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
                   if(principal != null && principal instanceof UserDetails)
                   {
                       UserDetails principalUserDetails = (UserDetails) principal;
                       Collection<? extends  GrantedAuthority> authorities = principalUserDetails.getAuthorities();
                       List<String> requiredRoles = Arrays.asList(jsv.springRoles().split(","));

                       for(String requiredRole : requiredRoles)
                       {
                           Feature f = new Feature();
                           f.setName(requiredRole);
                           if(authorities.contains(f))
                           // if The Method Have @JsonSpringView Behind it, and Current User has The Required Permission(Feature, Right, ... . Anything You may Name It).
                           return false;
                       }
                       // if The Method Have @JsonSpringView Behind it, but the Current User doesn't have The required Permission(Feature, Right, ... . Anything You may Name It).
                       return true;
                   }
               }
           }
           // if The Method Doesn't Have @JsonSpringView Behind it.
           return false;
       }
   }
   ```
3. Jersey servers have a default `ObjectMapper` for their serialization/deserialization purposes. If you're using such system and you want to change it's default ObjectMapper, Steps 3, 4 and 5 is yours, else you can read this step and your job is done here.

   ### JsonSpringObjectMapperProvider.java

   ```
   @Provider
   public class JsonSpringObjectMapperProvider implements ContextResolver<ObjectMapper>
   {
       ObjectMapper mapper;

       public JsonSpringObjectMapperProvider()
       {
           mapper = new ObjectMapper();
           AnnotationIntrospector one = new JsonSpringViewAnnotationIntrospector();
           AnnotationIntrospector two = new JacksonAnnotationIntrospector();
           AnnotationIntrospector three = AnnotationIntrospector.pair(one, two);

           mapper.setAnnotationIntrospector(three);
       }

       @Override
       public ObjectMapper getContext(Class<?> arg0) {
           return this.mapper;
       }
   }
   ```
4. You should extend `javax.ws.rs.core.Application` and mention Your class Name in Web.xml. Mine is RestApplication.Like this:

   ### RestApplication.java

   ```
   import java.util.HashSet;
   import java.util.Set;

   import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;

   public class RestApplication extends Application
   {
       public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() 
       {
           Set<Class<?>> classes = new HashSet<Class<?>>();
           classes.add(JsonSpringObjectMapperProvider.class);
           return classes ;
       }
   }
   ```
5. and this is the Last Step. you should mention your Application class (from step 4) in your web.xml:

   ### A part of my web.xml

   ```
   <servlet>
       <servlet-name>RestService</servlet-name>
       <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet</servlet-class>
       <init-param>
           <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.package</param-name>
           <param-value>your_restful_resources_package_here</param-value>
       </init-param>
       <init-param>
       <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
           <param-value>true</param-value>
       </init-param>
       <!-- THIS IS THE PART YOU SHOULD PPPAYYY ATTTTENTTTTION TO-->
       <init-param>
           <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
           <param-value>your_package_name_here.RestApplication</param-value>
       </init-param>
       <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
   </servlet>
   ```

and from now on You only need to mention the @JsonSpringView annotation Behind Any Property you want. Like this:

### PersonDataTransferObject.java

```
public class PersonDataTransferObject
{
    private String name;

    @JsonSpringView(springRoles="ADMIN, SUPERUSER")  // Only Admins And Super Users Will See the person National Code in the automatically produced Json.
    private String nationalCode;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me , the filter is only applied once with the first user who logs in. Please, can you look at my newer question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35558218/jackson-jsonignore-fields-based-on-spring-security-roles . Do you have an updated solution for this issue ?

Comment: Please let me know if anyone able to solve this issue? I am also facing same issue i.e., filter is only applied once with first user who logs in.

Comment: This is awesome, is there a chance to get your example updated for current spring version?

Comment: @BigDong i'm really sorry, currently i'm under heavy pressure to do my own tasks, so cant really update the answer :(

Comment: That's too bad. This should be implemented by default with spring-security.

Comment: Anyone could share a working project that use this lib, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Althou it is possible to write custom JSON processing filter (e.g. based on [JSON Pointers](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-pbryan-zyp-json-pointer-02)), it will be a little bit complex to do.

The simplest way is to create your own DTO and map only those properties, which the user is authorized to get.

Comment: Won't help if you want to return 10 fields to a user with `admin` role and only 3 fields to a user with `user` role. Unless you have inheritance and check the role inside the endpoint.

Comment: @prettyvoid I don't understand the comment. Can you elaborate a bit more? The solution I am describing consist of a single DTO class and a property mapper using few IF statements.

Comment: Nevermind sorry for the misleading comment, I thought you're only suggesting a DTO with a constructor that takes the class that have all the fields. But you made it clear when you said a property mapper with a few `if` statements.